# Magento Soap - Get detailed product list with one single call

Tags: magento, soap, magento-1.7, soap-client

I'm currently using a SOAP method called 'catalogProductList' (http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.list.html) that retrieves a Array of catalogProductEntity.

The problem is that `catalogProductEntity` doesn't have some attributes like 'price' and 'description'. The question is: Is there any (already implemented) SOAP method that gives me this information with one single call?

If don't, how/where can I add this fields to the returned values? I mean, change the php code in the server side to get this 'detailed list of products' in one single call.

I'm trying to avoid several queries to each product to get this info.

PS: I'm using Magento 1.7.

---

**Edited**

Following @Mat tips, I edited the \app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Api.php file and my method `items` is just like this:

```
public function items($filters = null, $store = null)
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addStoreFilter($this->_getStoreId($store))
        ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('description')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name');

    /** @var $apiHelper Mage_Api_Helper_Data */
    $apiHelper = Mage::helper('api');
    $filters = $apiHelper->parseFilters($filters, $this->_filtersMap);
    try {
        foreach ($filters as $field => $value) {
            $collection->addFieldToFilter($field, $value);
        }
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $this->_fault('filters_invalid', $e->getMessage());
    }
    $result = array();
    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        $result[] = array(
            'product_id' => $product->getId(),
            'sku'        => $product->getSku(),
            'price'      => $product->getData('price'),
            'description'=> $product->getData('description'),
            'name'       => $product->getName(),
            'set'        => $product->getAttributeSetId(),
            'type'       => $product->getTypeId(),
            'category_ids' => $product->getCategoryIds(),
            'website_ids'  => $product->getWebsiteIds()
        );
    }
    error_log(print_r($result, true) . "\n", 3, "c:\log.txt");
    return $result;
}
```

The log file outputs this result:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 3
            [sku] => sim12ple1235
            [price] => 99.9500
            [description] => Simple Description
            [name] => Simple Product
            [set] => 4
            [type] => simple
            [category_ids] => Array
                (
                )
            [website_ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

Note that price and description are in the $result variable, but the xml response I get in the client application is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:catalogProductListResponse>
<storeView SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns1:catalogProductEntity[1]" xsi:type="ns1:catalogProductEntityArray">
<item xsi:type="ns1:catalogProductEntity">
<product_id xsi:type="xsd:string">3</product_id>
<sku xsi:type="xsd:string">sim12ple1235</sku>
<name xsi:type="xsd:string">Simple Product</name>
<set xsi:type="xsd:string">4</set>
<type xsi:type="xsd:string">simple</type>
<category_ids SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[0]" xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOfString"/>
<website_ids SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOfString">
<item xsi:type="xsd:string">1</item>
</website_ids>
</item>
</storeView>
</ns1:catalogProductListResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My question is: Is there any xml schema or another config file that specifies the output? Anything else I'm missing to edit in the server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that it was missing this fields (price and description) in the file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/wsdl.xml, after applying the php change.

```
...
<complexType name="catalogProductEntity">
<all>
    <element name="product_id" type="xsd:string"/>
    <element name="sku" type="xsd:string"/>
    <element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
    <element name="set" type="xsd:string"/>
    <element name="type" type="xsd:string"/>
    <element name="category_ids" type="typens:ArrayOfString"/>
    <element name="website_ids" type="typens:ArrayOfString"/>

    <element name="price" type="xsd:string"/>
    <element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
</all>
</complexType>
...
```

**And DON'T FORGET CLEANING THE CACHE!**

Answer (score 3):

To get product info you have to use [catalog_product.info](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html)

You before get the list and then you cycle on list to get product detailed info.

```
$list = $proxy->catalogProductList($sessionId, $filters);
for($i = 0; $i < count($list); $i ++){
  $current = $list[$i];
  $product = $proxy->catalogProductInfo($sessionId, $current['product_id']);
}
```

//// UPDATE ////

to change catalogProductList code go to

```
\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Api.php
```

and add parameters you need in

```
public function items
```

doing something like this before the cycle

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addStoreFilter($this->_getStoreId($store))
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name');
```

where you have to add

```
->addAttributeToSelect('what_you_need');
```

to

```
    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        $result[] = array(
            'product_id' => $product->getId(),
            'sku'        => $product->getSku(),
            'name'       => $product->getName(),
            'set'        => $product->getAttributeSetId(),
            'type'       => $product->getTypeId(),
            'category_ids' => $product->getCategoryIds(),
            'website_ids'  => $product->getWebsiteIds(),
            'what_you_need' => $product->getData('what_you_need')

        );
    }
```

//// UPDATE /// (thanks to @matheusjardimb)

For last you have to add

```
what_you_need
```

element to

```
app/code/core/mage/catalog/etc/wsdl.xml
```

in this part of xml

```
<complexType name="catalogProductEntity">
            <all>
                <element name="product_id" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="sku" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="set" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="type" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="category_ids" type="typens:ArrayOfString"/>
                <element name="website_ids" type="typens:ArrayOfString"/>
                <element name="**what_you_need**" type="xsd:string"/>
            </all>
        </complexType>
```

Comment: But this approach implies in two soap method calls. I'm working in a Android client, and I'm trying to save network resources.

Comment: if you have a list of product_id saved somewhere you can use directly catalogProductInfo

Comment: ok, with no standard function you can do this, but you can try to change api of catalogProductList to return what you need.
Look for this file
`\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Api.php`
In `public function items`
insert what you need in the result array

Comment: Thanks! I've found this function and seems that what I'm looking for is over there.

Comment: It's a shame that we can't get this basic values with one single call by default. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: damn...
why not? i updated the code above, you can't get data in that way? Doing that you have in your returned array you have to find what you need.

Comment: I've added my progress, could you please take a look on that?

Comment: completed my answer for future user, +1 for you

Comment: @Mat If I will follow your instructions will I be getting the "what you need" element in xml format if I run. http://magento/rfg/api/v2_soap/index?wsdl=1

Comment: Next time create custom module - do not modify core files.